# CMA ES equivalent in python having same function in R

Tags: optimization

What is the equivalent function in python for cma_es in R, we have par, function, lower and upper bounds of variables for R?

For python, we have

es = CMAEvolutionStrategy(x0, sigma0).optimize(objective_fct) which doesn't have lower and upper bound. Is there anyway I can define lower and upper bounds of variables in python?

Answer (score 2):

In the python `cma` package you can specify bound constraints:

Suppose you want to constraint the first coordinate to be in [-2, 2] in a 2-dimensional optimisation problem:

```
import cma
opts = cma.CMAOptions()
opts.set("bounds", [[-2, None], [2, None]])
cma.fmin(cost_function, x_start, sigma_start, opts)
```

(you can also pass a scalar for lower and upper bounds, which is applied to each coordinate)